# Trim output in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this query

```
 Select distinct 
    tag 
 from 
     (SELECT  *
      FROM [piarchive].[picomp2]
      WHERE tag like '%CPU_Active' 
        and time between '2014/10/01 10:13:08' and '2014/10/01 10:18:37'
        and value = -524289 
      order by time desc) as t1
```

With this I am getting output

```
RSV23.VMS_CPU01_1_0.CPU_Active
```

I need to trim this output to

```
RSV23.VMS_CPU1_1_0
```

And need to use this trim output in different query like below

```
 SELECT  *
 FROM [piarchive].[picomp2]
 WHERE tag like 'RSV23.VMS_CPU01_1_0%' and tag not like '%CPU_Active' and  time   
 between '2014/10/01 10:13:08'and'2014/10/01 10:18:37'  order by time desc
```

How can I trim first out and use that output in second query?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson its basically PI database server but there not option for PI that's why I put sql and my sql both

Comment: Ah, had never heard of that database server :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I think sql server syntax and query will work

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer.

```
 SELECT top 6 *
 FROM [piarchive].[picomp2]
 WHERE tag like 
 (
   Select distinct left(tag,19) + '%' 
   from (SELECT  *
   FROM [piarchive].[picomp2]
   WHERE tag like '%CPU_Active' and  time between '2014/10/01 10:13:08'and'2014/10/01 10:18:37'
   and value=-524289 order by time desc) as t1
 )  
   and tag not like '%CPU_Active' and tag not like '%Program%' and time between '2014/10/01  
   10:13:08'and'2014/10/01 10:18:37'  order by time desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find last index of dot (.) in query result and chop the string after that index.

```
declare @result nvarchar(100)
set @result = (Select distinct tag from (SELECT  * FROM [piarchive].[picomp2] WHERE tag like '%CPU_Active' and time between '2014/10/01 10:13:08' and '2014/10/01 10:18:37' and value = -524289 order by time desc) as t1)

declare @LastIndex int 
set @LastIndex = len(@result) - charindex('.', reverse(@result))

substring(@result,0,@LastIndex) // this will give you the required result
```